# Help with finding the generating function (with a constant )

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, generating-functions

How do you get the generating function from this formula:

$8(1+x)^{7}$

I have the following formula for $(1+x)^{n}$ :

$n\choose 0$ + $n \choose 1$$x^1$ + $n \choose 2$$x^2$+... +$n \choose n$$x^n$

so shouldn't this mean for this formula it should be:

8$7 \choose 0$$x^0$+8$7 \choose 1$$x^1$+8$7 \choose 2$$x^2$+....+8$7 \choose 7$$x^7$

but this doesn't seem to be equivalent to the book's answer of:

$8 \choose 1$$x^0$+2$8 \choose 2$$x^1$+3$8 \choose 3$$x^2$+....+8$8 \choose 8$$x^7$

Why is the 8 incrementing up instead of being multiplied by each element of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they have is the same as what you have. $$8\begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ k  \end{pmatrix} = (k+1)\begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ k +1  \end{pmatrix}\,.$$

To see this,

$$8\times {7!\over k! (7-k!)} = {8!\over k! (8 - 1 - k)!} = {8!\over k!(8-(k+1))!} $$
$$ = (k+1)\times {8!\over (k+1)!(8 - (k+1))!} = {8!\over k! (8 - (k+1))!} \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n\geq 1$.  Note that
$$
n\binom{8}{n}=n\cdot\frac{8!}{n!(8-n)!}=n\cdot\frac{8\cdot 7!}{n\cdot(n-1)!\cdot(8-n)!}.
$$
The $n$ in the denominator now cancels:
$$
n\binom{8}{n}=8\cdot\frac{7!}{(n-1)!(8-n)!}.
$$
Finally, because we can write $8-n=7-(n-1)$, we have
$$
n\binom{8}{n}=8\cdot\frac{7!}{(n-1)!(7-(n-1))!}=8\binom{7}{n-1}.
$$